# MySQL data crunching. How to get the values after the slash from database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm crunching some data from a MySQL database on towns and regions within a town.

The database looks something like this

```
ID | NAME
1  | Manchester
2  | Manchester/North
3  | Manchester/South
4  | Manchester/East
5  | Manchester/West
```

I've tried a PHP script that will find only the words that come after the `/` and produce a number based on a count variable`$j` but so far its not working. Later on I plan to write this into the JSON file where the variable `$data` comes from.

My ideal output will be `north south east west` `4`

Here is the script

```
$j=0;
foreach($data->objects->layer->geometries as &$h)
{
   foreach($result as $row)
   {
     preg_match("/[^\/]+$/", $row['name'], $matches); // Town/Region
     $no_slash = $matches[0]; // Region
     if(strtolower($h->properties->name) == $no_slash)
     {
        $h->properties->id = $row['id'];
        $j++;

        echo $j . " " . $no_slash . "<br />";
     }
 } 
} 

echo "Number of matches: " . $j;
```

My output at the moment is `Number of matches: 0` Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use this MySQL query:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(NAME, '/', 1) AS city,
  GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NAME, '/', -1) SEPARATOR ' ') AS districts,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  tablename
WHERE
  NAME like '%/%'
GROUP BY
  city
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfcf1/1).

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`ID` int, `NAME` varchar(16))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`ID`, `NAME`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Manchester'),
    (2, 'Manchester/North'),
    (3, 'Manchester/South'),
    (4, 'Manchester/East'),
    (5, 'Manchester/West');
```

Query:

```
SELECT
SUBSTRING(Name, 1, LOCATE('/', Name) - 1) Town,
CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(SUBSTRING(Name, LOCATE('/', Name) + 1)), ': ', COUNT(*)) AS Regions
FROM t
WHERE Name LIKE '%/%'
GROUP BY Town;
```

Output:

```
|       TOWN |                  REGIONS |
|------------|--------------------------|
| Manchester | North,South,East,West: 4 |
```

- [live demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d5db52/6/0)